# Breakpoint bug in Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), I’ve discovered what I think may be a bug.  I’ve set some breakpoints in some Powershell code and debugged.  I then decided to remove the breakpoints (F9) and run again.  However, Visual Studio Code must cache the breakpoints because they still break when I run the code.

Is this a legitimate bug? Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: *Is this a legitimate bug?* - No;  This is how breakpoints have always worked in Visual Studio.

Comment: It's not Visual Studio.  It's Visual Studio Code.  And, once I remove a breakpoint, I do not expect it to 'hit' when I run the code again.

Comment: It still isn't a bug.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, once I set a breakpoint it's active even if I remove it?  The only way to remove it is to restart the editor?

Comment: In the situation you describe that is indeed the case

Comment: FWIW, this does not sound like the expected behavior to me.  Have you checked that you have the latest version of the Powershell Extension for VS Code?  Perhpas try the "Reapply All Breakpoints" command after starting your debugging session.

Comment: Looks like [this issue has already been reported](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/625). looks like there is a [workaround](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/625#issuecomment-290929624).

Comment: @heavyd - Thanks!  I knew I was not crazy.  I agree this is not expected behavior.

Comment: @heavyd, you may post your comment as an answer – some people might not search in the comments for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, this is a bug reported here: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/625#issuecomment-290929624

The workaround is to only remove breakpoints while the debugger is running.